# sql running days between ordered pairs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this data structure:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d9edf

```
CREATE TABLE orders
(
product CHAR(5),
shipdate DATETIME,
status CHAR(25)
);
 
INSERT INTO orders(product, shipdate, status) VALUES ('aa', '2021-01-15', 'ordered');
INSERT INTO orders(product, shipdate, status) VALUES ('aa', '2021-01-20', 'ordered');
INSERT INTO orders(product, shipdate, status) VALUES ('aa', '2021-01-21', 'received');
INSERT INTO orders(product, shipdate, status) VALUES ('aa', '2021-01-22', 'received');
INSERT INTO orders(product, shipdate, status) VALUES ('aa', '2021-01-23', 'ordered');
INSERT INTO orders(product, shipdate, status) VALUES ('aa', '2021-01-28', 'received');
```

I wanted to calculate the days between the first occurrence of 'ordered' and the next time I hit a 'received', ordered by shipdate.

So starting out, I would skip the 2nd 'ordered' record, then land on the received record, then calculate datediff(days,'2021-01-21','2021-01-15') = 6
The next line, I start counting at 'ordered' for '2021-01-20', but I want to skip the next 'received' because I just previously counted it, so I would go to the 2nd 'received' for '2021-01-22'.

My output would look like:

```
('product', 'shipdate', 'status', 'days_between')
('aa', '2021-01-21', 'received', 6)
('aa', '2021-01-22', 'received', 2)
('aa', '2021-01-28', 'received', 5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually pretty simple logic.  Just enumerate the rows by status and aggregate.  The following assumes that orders are before received:

```
select o.product, min(shipdate),
       datediff(day, min(shipdate), nullif(max(shipdate), min(shipdate))) 
from (select o.*,
             row_number() over (partition by product, status order by shipdate) as seqnum
      from orders o
      where status in ('ordered', 'received')
     ) o
group by product, seqnum;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d9edf/6) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` to assign an effective Id to each set of ordered and received status, then self-join to get the corresponding dates and subtract.

```
with o as (
    select *, Row_Number() over (partition by product, status order by shipdate) n
    from orders
)
select o.product, o.shipdate, r.status, DateDiff(day,o.shipdate,r.shipdate) Days_Between
from o 
join o r on r.product=o.product and r.n=o.n and r.status='received'
where o.status='ordered'
```